# Help identifying a 4 pin SMD component of an USB device

Tags: pcb, components, identification

I received a really cool 10 port docking station for any device. I can sync devices too, but the USB port was almost sheered off. It looks like it was pushed back too far at one point. It also seemingly nearly sheered the thing in the picture off too.
[image]

I think I can clean it up and resolder it, but what the heck is it? There didn't seem to be any markings on it at all!

Comment: What a mess. What the heck caused that kind of damage. Anyway, looks like an inductor. A photo that clearly shows the reference designator under the part would help, it's upside down and partially obscured here. L11?

Comment: @replete doh! I made the mistake of putting it back together.  I did not see any other text on the inductor, that was just a smudge of white. Can I just use any inductor and hope that it works? As for the damage, the USB port (which was where those holes were, I desoldered it since I plan to replace) was shoved back at one point

Comment: Almost looks like a common mode choke. If those those traces are the data lines, that would be pretty odd. Can you confirm if those traces go to the USB connector?

Comment: Please provide a sharp macro photo with better lighting and a picture showing the whole PCB

Comment: What's the designator next to it? I see "11", but what is the prefix? If it's "L" then it would most likely be a common-mode choke. Those are pretty common in USB circuits

Comment: Yes it is a USB data circuit. I cannot get any more pics right now I am away from my home for a week, but I appreciate the comments. I will update when I get home.

Answer (score 1):

USB data lines can have:

1) Series termination resistors, but are usually placed near the USB controller.

2) ESD protection diodes near connectors. Diodes are not placed in series with the data line. ESD diodes must have pins connected to Ground and VBUS.

3) Common mode choke in series with the data line and usually placed near the connector. Looks like the component shown in the pic is a common mode choke.